# Do Recurrent Neural Networks assume stationarity or just a general kind of sequential dependence?

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, stationarity, recurrent-neural-network

Just when I thought I had convinced myself that RNNs make no other assumption about a sequence other than that there are dependencies between the inputs and that (in the case of monodirectional RNNs) the past affects the present, Goodfellow, Bengio and Courville (2016) hit me with this:

"The parameter sharing used in recurrent networks relies on the assumption that the same parameters can be used for different time-steps. Equivalently, the assumption is that the conditional probability distribution over the variables at time t + 1 gives the variables at time t is **stationary**, meaning that the relationship between the previous time step and the next time step does not depend on t."

Could someone elaborate on what this means with regards to the stationarity assumption for the time series?

(I have the feeling that there is a notion of local or "input-conditioned" stationarity here but that is just my intuition.)

Answer (score 2):

"The parameter sharing used in recurrent networks relies on the assumption that the same parameters can be used for different time-steps". I think this is valid because the RNN is taught to be timestep agnostic in a sense that it conditions on the context $h_{t - 1}$ and on the input $x_t$, so in this case it doesn't depend on the $t$ itself. I think by stationarity they mean that if the context is same and the input is same, the output will be same regardless of the t (so in a sense it's different than fitting a linear regression which is directly dependent on $t$).

Comment: Awesome that helps alot, thank you!

Comment: Yes, this answer is correct. The same argument applies to classical structured prediction models like the HMM.